# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' even after installed

Tags: python, selenium

I keep getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'" even after I installed selenium. I ran the command

`pip show selenium`

and get

```
Version: 3.141.0
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
```

so it seems like I do have it installed. But in vscode when I type in

`from selenium import webdriver` it says the module can't be found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: most likely you have more than one python and selenium is installed for different interpreter than the one used to run the code is VSCode

Comment: try: `pip3 install selenium`

Comment: @buran most likely has the correct answer.  It is very easy to be using the "wrong" interpreter in VS Code.  Check to make sure it's the same one where your Selenium package is installed

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your **VS Code**, it might work. If it doesn’t help then try reinstalling **selenium** or make sure that python interpreter in **VS Code**.
Thanks